# 7th Degree Differential Homogeneous Operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators, homogeneous-equation

Question asks:

$1,  1 - i,  i,  i$ are the roots of $L ( r ) = 0$  (characteristic equation)
where $L(D)$ is a $7^{\text {th}}$ ( seventh) order linear, homogeneous differential operator with constant coefficients.

Find the differential equation $L (D) y = 0$ and its general solution.

Which way should i follow to solve this problem ?

Comment: can you give more specific answer, still could not get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 1 \implies (r-1)$$
$$i \implies (r^2+1)$$
Again $i$:
$$i \implies (r^2+1)^2$$
$$(1-i) \implies (r-(1-i))(r-(1+i))$$
So that you have:
$$P(r)=(r-1)(r^2+1)^2(r-(1-i))(r-(1+i))$$
$$P(r)=(r-1)(r^2+1)^2((r-1)^2+1)$$
You can easily deduce the differential equation from the characteristic polynomial:
$$((D-1)(D^2+1)^2((D-1)^2+1))y=0$$
Where $D=\dfrac {d}{dx}$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the general solution, you just need to add up the solutions coming from each factor in the characteristic polynomial...
$$
y = c_1 e^x + \underbrace{(c_2x+c_3)\sin x + (c_4x+c_5)\cos x} + \underbrace{(c_6 \sin x +c_7 \sin x)e^x}. 
$$